# Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS in core data project

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

My app crashes on updating existing object after view recreation (reselecting it in menu list).  Crash happens either in `- (BOOL)shouldSetValue:(id *)value forKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath usingMapping:(RKPropertyMapping *)propertyMapping` method or in saving data one.

I've tried to reproduce this issue in a [new demo project](https://github.com/hryamzik/RestKitCrash) but it works perfectly so this fact confuses me even more.

Let me add a few more details:

I get stuck here:
`objective-c
id currentValue = [self.destinationObject valueForKeyPath:keyPath];`

Object exists (in my project it's a `User` instance, not an `Address` one :

`(lldb) po [self.destinationObject class]
User
(lldb) po self.destinationObject
<User: 0xdabcd80> (entity: User; id: 0x1383f350 <x-coredata://66768786-A8C7-4A5B-B486-48DE8A3684FE/User/p1> ; data: <fault>)`

It's retain count is positive:

`(lldb) po (int)[self.destinationObject retainCount]
9`

but accessing object attributes doesn't work:

```
(lldb) po (int)[self.destinationObject name]
error: Execution was interrupted.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

(lldb) po [self.destinationObject valueForKeyPath:@"name"]
error: Execution was interrupted.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

My guess is that there's something wrong with a managed context here. What are the next possible steps to investigate this?

P.S.: Here's the instruments allocations:

[image]

P.P.S: also posted this in the restkit project but didn't get any replies.

**Update**:

Profiled with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` and zombies, without retain counts, didn't get any further:

[image]

And I can't get it crashed with `DebuggingCoreDataConcurrency...`.

Comment: Try using a different attribute instead of "name" e.g. "userName".

Comment: turn on thread debugging for core data, and zombies, and don't use / trust retain count

Comment: Agree with Wain: add thread debugging and ignoring retain count. See http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Comment: @eric-hedstrom, tried your advise but didn't really get any further. Updated my post.